# Windows Server 2012 2TB drive limit on 3TB drive - UEFI, GUID

Tags: windows-server-2012, uefi, guid

We've got a Dell Poweredge T410, and have upgraded to two raided 3TB hard drives, and Windows Server 2012 Standard. The drive is only showing as 2TB, and I can't see why. We're using UEFI and GUID partition table.

Are additional drivers needed? Or could my hardware (the one that came with the system) be affecting this?

Thanks,

David

Comment: 3TB drives aren't listed in the specs for that server so my guess is that the hardware doesn't in fact support drives of that size. The easiest, most efiicient way to answer this definitively is to give Dell tech support a call and ask them.

Comment: Thanks @joeqwerty - I'll give that a go, however others report being able to use 3TB drives, so still confused!

Comment: Waht exact drives?  Same as the ones reported to be working?

Comment: Yeah, Seagate Barracuda drives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably due to the RAID adapter, Windows is able to use 3TB drives just fine.

The real problem used to be booting from drives bigger than 2.2TB on non EFI systems

Comment: Spot on - turns out the RAID adapter needed a firmware update. thanks